Strict-Transport-Security max-age not updating to 31536000 in ASP.NET Core application
I am trying to set the Strict-Transport-Security header in my ASP.NET Core application to enforce HTTPS with a max-age of 1 year (31536000 seconds), along with includeSubDomains and preload. However, when I check the headers in the browser, the max-age value is always set to 2592000 (30 days) instead of 31536000.
Here is the middleware code I am using:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Append("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload");
    }
    await next();
});

I have also verified that:

The application is running in the production environment (env.IsDevelopment() is false).
The browser cache has been cleared.
The application is deployed on Azure with HTTPS enabled.

Why is the max-age value in the Strict-Transport-Security header not updating to 31536000? Is there any configuration in Azure or ASP.NET Core that might override this value?

Did you try it with new App Service?

To cross check once again, remove if (!env.IsDevelopment()) condition,redeploy ,restart and check the app service

I am able to get the new value using middleware.Image

Initially even I was facing issue when I tried with your code. Able to get the new value using middleware. Please check the below sol.

To address your issue, it's important to configure HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) properly in your ASP.NET Core application. Instead of manually appending headers, you should use the built-in HSTS middleware provided by ASP.NET Core. This ensures consistency and avoids potential conflicts with other configurations or hosting environments like Azure.
Here’s how you can configure HSTS in the Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true; // Enables the preload directive
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true; // Applies the policy to all subdomains
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365); // Sets max-age to 1 year (31536000 seconds)
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("example.com"); // Example: Exclude certain hosts if needed
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("www.example.com");
});


In addition to your Solution, check the below one
Create a new Middleware Class file and add the below code.
Thanks @meenakshiBalekar for the sample code.
My Middleware.cs:
 public class Middleware
 {
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

     public Middleware(RequestDelegate next)
     {
         _next = next;
     }

     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
     {
         httpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
         {
             httpContext.Response.Headers["strict-transport-security"] = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         });
         await _next(httpContext);

     }
 }

 public static class MiddlewareExtensions
 {
     public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
     {
         return builder.UseMiddleware<Middleware>();
     }
 }


Register this in Program.cs file:

app.UseMiddleware<Middleware>();

Output:

